# Free objects in the category of groups with operators.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

> Consider the category $\mathbf{C}$ of groups with a given operator
>   domain $\Omega$. It's true that for every set $X$ there is a free
>   object $G$ on $X$?

I believe it's true and that the underlying group to $G$ must be a free group on $X$. But I don't know how to define the action of the operators in such a way that $G$ becomes a free object.

Comment: I don't know what an operator domain is, but you might find the adjoint functor theorems useful: you want to find a left adjoint to the forgetful functor "groups with given operator domain" to "sets".

Comment: If the category of groups-with-given-operator-domain has equalisers and small products, and has a co-separating set, then it's enough for the forgetful functor to preserve all small limits (by the Special Adjoint Functor Theorem, since that category is already locally small and well-powered, and Sets is locally small).